# Is there any option to enable or disable php FTP overwrite in remote server . ?

Tags: php, server, ftp

I can not overwrite files on remote server while uploading using php script ** ftp_put();
Is there any option or function to enable overwrite in ftp_put

Comment: What does it mean *"I cannot"*?  Do you get any error? Or what does the `ftp_put` do? - Can you overwrite the files using any standalone FTP client?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Comment: `ftp_put` will overwrite if it can. If it can't, it's a (FTP) server issue, not a php issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this.!!

If `ft_put` fails try `ftp_pasv` (Passive mode).

```
$connect = ftp_connect($ftp) or die("Unable to connect to host");
ftp_login($connect, $username, $pwd) or die("Authorization Failed");
// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($connect, true);
```

Comment: @UdayKumar Ask a better question first!

Comment: Ok . I will next time @MartinPrikryl . I solved my problem. 

ftp_put is always overwrite files .
I was making a mistake in setting the remote directory.

Comment: So why did you accept an answer that does not answer your question? Either post the actual solution, or even better, delete your question altogether, as no one could ever have correctly answered that.

Comment: Why you are thinking that this is an invalid or unnecessary question ? I just stucked here for 1 days and you are saying this is not a valid question . 

If you cant answer please keep quit @MartinPrikryl

Comment: Because you didn't provide enough information for anyone to even guess, let only know, the answer - Moreover, you actually asked the same question already: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46539038/850848